# Items in the doc sidebar are not activated automatically

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sidebar

I copied this example in [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/KyleMit/v6zhz/53/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=v6zhz) to make a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cOLOAnGro39WBmF93E4S?p=preview). But the items in the sidebar can not be activated while scrolling. The follows are external links.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I also tried to copy them into 3 proper files, and test locally on my machine. It is the same problem.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddle is running the jQuery after page load. The plunker is not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.bs-docs-sidebar',
    offset: 40
  });
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/qiojBFqmZcpclWWpDbrb?p=preview